# Регулярное выражение: ищем строки 5 типов, формируем list

Tags: регулярные-выражения, r

обрабатываю текст, содержащий наименования документов. Нужно вынуть все наименования документов и поместить в list или вектор. Пример текста:

```
ва ыва ыа Приложение №222-П пвапвап, 
Инсткурцию №155, пп.2.2, 
3.3.3 рекомендаций «Правила поведения пр ЧС», Инструкцию №155-АВ 

п.139--155 Приказа №ОКК4-1654, п.1.4 приложения А11 к Приказу №ОТК7-1984
п.11 Порядка №17-21-19-1/61212177, Приложение №33П, п.11 Порядка №15-1-21-14/2647586
```

Я наколхозил регулярку, которая собирает почти все наименования

```
([А-Я][а-я]*?)(\s\W[0-9]+[А-Я]+)|([А-Я][а-я]*?)(\s\W[0-9]+-[А-Я]+)|([А-Я][а-я]*?)(\s\W[0-9]+)|([А-Я][а-я]*?)(\s\W[А-Я]+[0-9]\W[0-9]+)
```

Не отлавливаются только следующие:

```
Порядка №17-21-19-1/61212177 и Порядка №15-1-21-14/2647586
```

Причём я и для такого типа наколхозил регулярку

```
([А-Я][а-я]*?)(\s\W[0-9]+\W[0-9]\W[0-9]\W[0-9]\W[0-9]+)
```

Но если я ее леплю к выражению, описанному выше, намимования всё равно не отлавливаются.
Помогите составить человеческую регулярку. И вообще, сколько логических ИЛИ можно использовать в выражении?

Вот пример работы:

```
library(stringr)  
text <- 'ва ыва ыа Приложение №222-П пвапвап, 
Инсткурцию №155, пп.2.2, 
3.3.3 рекомендаций «Правила поведения пр ЧС», Инструкцию №155-АВ 

п.139--155 Приказа №ОКК4-1654, п.1.4 приложения А11 к Приказу №ОТК7-1984
п.11 Порядка №17-21-19-1/61212177, Приложение №33П, п.11 Порядка №15-1-21-14/2647586'

str_extract_all(text, '([А-Я][а-я]*?)(\\s\\W[0-9]+\\W[0-9]\\W[0-9]\\W[0-9]\\W[0-9]+)|([А-Я][а-я]*?)(\\s\\W[0-9]+[А-Я]+)|([А-Я][а-я]*?)(\\s\\W[0-9]+-[А-Я]+)|([А-Я][а-я]*?)(\\s\\W[0-9]+)|([А-Я][а-я]*?)(\\s\\W[А-Я]+[0-9]\\W[0-9]+)')
```

Comment: Александр, благодарю за науку. Буду знать как оформлять.

Comment: например: `str_extract_all(text, '[А-Я][а-я]+ №[^., \n]+')`

Comment: Александр, спасибо большое за помощь! Карсивая регулярка в 22 символа! Супер!